# Increase precision in SelfAdjointEigenSolver in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, eigenvalue, eigenvector, eigen3

I am trying to determine the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a sparse array in Eigen. Since I need to compute all the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, and I could not get this done using the unsupported ArpackSupport module working, I chose to convert the system to a dense matrix and compute the eigensystem using SelfAdjointEigenSolver (I know my matrix is real and has real eigenvalues). This works well until I have matrices of size 1024*1024 but then I start getting deviations from the expected results.

In the documentation of this module (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointEigenSolver.html) from what I understood it is possible to change the number of max iterations:

> const int m_maxIterations
>   static
>   Maximum number of iterations.
>
> The algorithm terminates if it does not converge within m_maxIterations * n iterations, where n denotes the size of the matrix. This value is currently set to 30 (copied from LAPACK).

However, I do not understand how do you implement this, using their examples:

```
SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Matrix4f> es;
Matrix4f X = Matrix4f::Random(4,4);
Matrix4f A = X + X.transpose();
es.compute(A);
cout << "The eigenvalues of A are: " <<   es.eigenvalues().transpose() << endl;
es.compute(A + Matrix4f::Identity(4,4)); // re-use es to compute eigenvalues of A+I
cout << "The eigenvalues of A+I are: " << es.eigenvalues().transpose() << endl
```

How would you modify it in order to change the maximum number of iterations?

Additionally, will this solve my problem or should I try to find an alternative function or algorithm to solve the eigensystem?

My thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing the Jacobi algorithm adapted from the Book Numerical Recipes:

```
void ROTATy(MatrixXd &a, int i, int j, int k, int l, double s, double tau)
{
double g,h;
g=a(i,j);
h=a(k,l);
a(i,j)=g-s*(h+g*tau);
a(k,l)=h+s*(g-h*tau);

}

void jacoby(int n, MatrixXd &a, MatrixXd &v, VectorXd &d )
{
int j,iq,ip,i;
double tresh,theta,tau,t,sm,s,h,g,c;


VectorXd b(n);
VectorXd z(n);

v.setIdentity();    
z.setZero();


for (ip=0;ip<n;ip++)
{   
    d(ip)=a(ip,ip);
    b(ip)=d(ip);
}


for (i=0;i<50;i++) 
{
    sm=0.0;
    for (ip=0;ip<n-1;ip++) 
    {

        for (iq=ip+1;iq<n;iq++)
            sm += fabs(a(ip,iq));
    }

    if (sm == 0.0) {
        break;
    }

    if (i < 3)
    tresh=0.2*sm/(n*n); 
    else
    tresh=0.0;  


    for (ip=0;ip<n-1;ip++)
    {
        for (iq=ip+1;iq<n;iq++)
        {
            g=100.0*fabs(a(ip,iq));
            if (i > 3 && (fabs(d(ip))+g) == fabs(d[ip]) && (fabs(d[iq])+g) == fabs(d[iq]))
            a(ip,iq)=0.0;
            else if (fabs(a(ip,iq)) > tresh)
            {
                h=d(iq)-d(ip);
                if ((fabs(h)+g) == fabs(h))
                {
                    t=(a(ip,iq))/h;
                }   
                else 
                {
                    theta=0.5*h/(a(ip,iq));
                    t=1.0/(fabs(theta)+sqrt(1.0+theta*theta));
                    if (theta < 0.0)
                    {
                        t = -t;
                    }
                    c=1.0/sqrt(1+t*t);
                    s=t*c;
                    tau=s/(1.0+c);
                    h=t*a(ip,iq);


                    z(ip)=z(ip)-h;
                    z(iq)=z(iq)+h;
                    d(ip)=d(ip)- h;
                    d(iq)=d(iq) + h;
                    a(ip,iq)=0.0;


                    for (j=0;j<ip;j++)
                        ROTATy(a,j,ip,j,iq,s,tau);
                    for (j=ip+1;j<iq;j++)
                        ROTATy(a,ip,j,j,iq,s,tau);
                    for (j=iq+1;j<n;j++)
                        ROTATy(a,ip,j,iq,j,s,tau);
                    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
                        ROTATy(v,j,ip,j,iq,s,tau);


                }
            } 
        }
    }


}
```

}

the function jacoby receives the size of of the square matrix n, the matrix we want to calculate the we want to solve (a) and a matrix that will receive the eigenvectors in each column and a vector that is going to receive the eigenvalues. It is a bit slower so I tried to parallelize it with OpenMp (see: [Parallelization of Jacobi algorithm using eigen c++ using openmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880346/parallelization-of-jacobi-algorithm-using-eigen-c-using-openmp?noredirect=1#comment67070602_39880346)) but for 4096x4096 sized matrices what I did not mean an improvement in computation time, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the number of iterations is unlikely to help. On the other hand, moving from `float` to `double` will help a lot!

If that does not help, please, be more specific on "deviations from the expected results".

Comment: Basically after I obtain the eigenvectors I need to compute an expectation value, that is calculate something like: [a_1.....a_m]*M*[a_1.....a_m]^T, a_m being the coefficients of the eigenvectors. I expect to obtain integer values. For a 256*256 matrix for all the eigenvectors I obtain something like 4.999999... but for a 1024*1024 matrix almost all of them work, but I also obtain something like 0.2 and 0.4. Physically speaking it would be impossible not to obtain non integer values, and 0.2 and 0.4 a a bit too far off.

Comment: And have you tried with double precision? (i.e., with `MatrixXd`). You can also check the accuracy by testing that the input matrix is properly reconstructed: `norm(A-(eig.eigenvectors()*eig.eigenvalues().asDiagonal()).eval()*eig.eigenvectors().transpose()) / norm(A)`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it, all my matrices are implemented using double precision, I wonder if trying quadruple precision would be worth a shot.

Comment: OK, so what about the precision test I suggested above? If it returns something like 1e-15, there not much we can do on the solver side. Also, it could be interesting to check the eigenvalues for their range and multiplicity.

Answer (score 1):

`m_maxIterations` is a `static const int` variable, and as such it can be considered an intrinsic property of the type. Changing such a type property usually would be done via a specific template parameter. In this case, however, it is set to the constant number `30`, so it's not possible.

Therefore, you're only choice is to change the value in the header file and recompile your program.

However, before doing that, I would try the [Singular Value Decomposition](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicLinearAlgebraDecompositions.html). According to the homepage, its accuracy is "Excellent-Proven". Moreover, it can overcome problems due to numerically not completely symmetric matrices.

Comment: Do you mean Jacobi SVD? If so could you elaborate on how do I get Eigevalues and Eigenvectors from this decomposition?